# JQuery Remove Click Function Removes Only Most Recent Call

Tags: php, jquery

I have been trying to code a reading list, to which you can add the articles you like and then click a small x at the top to delete them from the list. I use JQuery .click to remove the story from the database, removing it from the list. But, when I try to delete multiple stories at a time, it only deletes the last one clicked. I don't know what it could be. I thought it might be something with global vs local variables, but i don't know where to begin.

Here is some of the HTML, a div similar to the one I delete:

```
<li id="arrayorder_146">
<div class="reading_list drop-shadow lifted">
<div class="reading_list_container">
<a class="deletefromrl" data-storyid="146" data-parent="arrayorder_146">x</a>
<p class="reading_list_story">
<a class="rlstory" href="" data-storyid="146">iSteal: Apple Products Cause NYC Crime Wave
</a></p></div></div></li>
```

Here is the JQuery Function:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ $(function() {
        $('a.deletefromrl').click(function(){
            $(this).closest('li').fadeOut('slow');
            var order = $('#list ul').sortable("serialize") + '&update=update' + '&id=' + $(this).attr('data-storyid'); 
            $.post("deletefromReadingList.php", order, function(theResponse){
                    $("#response").html(theResponse);
                });
```

Here is the php deletefromReadingList:

```
    <?php 
 require_once('compress.php');
  require_once('startsession.php');
 require_once('admin_start_session.php');
 require_once('db_connect_variables.php');
 require_once('input_variables.php');

 $array = $_POST['arrayorder'];
 $id = $_POST['id'];

if ($_POST['update'] == "update")
 {
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$admin_id = $_SESSION['admin_id'];

$listorder = '';
$i=0;

foreach ($array as $idval) 
{
    if(($idval == $id) && ($i == 0))
    {
        $i++;
        continue;
    }
    $listorder = $listorder . $idval . ',';
}

$listorder = substr_replace($listorder ,"",-1);

if(!empty($user_id) && empty($admin_id))
{
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        $query = "UPDATE reading_list SET listorder = " . $listorder . " WHERE user_id = " . $user_id;
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        echo 'Saved until 9AM Tomorrow';
}
else if(empty($user_id) && !empty($admin_id))
{
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        $query = "UPDATE reading_list SET listorder = '" . $listorder . "' WHERE admin_id = " . $admin_id;
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        echo 'Saved until 9AM Tomorrow';
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['readinglist'] = $listorder;
    setcookie('readinglist', $listorder, mktime(6, 59, 59, date('m'), (date('d')+1), date('y')));    // expires at midnight
    echo 'Saved until 9AM Tomorrow';
}
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Your PHP code contains SQL with syntax errors.  You're using mysqli, why aren't you using [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)?

Comment: Where would I use the prepared statements? I'm also having trouble finding some syntax errors.

Comment: "I don't know where to begin." The place to start would be isolating this in a sharable URL with something like jsFiddle. Your problem is almost certainly related to just the JS, so you want to isolate your components and focus on only the part that's relevant. You can also then easily get help from others.

Comment: Ok I'll make a jsFiddle now

Comment: Ok here it is, but for some reason nothings working. http://jsfiddle.net/fQrmn/

Also here is the link the demo - www.cgrtutoring.com/index7.php